# Regex to not not match exactly against a list

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regular expression for an html5 input pattern attribute for "is not one of the following items".

How do I make

- ab
- aba
- ba

into a pattern that matches anything that is *not exactly* one of these words.

So for example what I want is for

- ab - **not match**
- abab - **match**
- bab - **match**
- b - **match**
- ab a - **match**

In other words,  I want the regex equivalent of (in javascript)

```
! ['ab', 'aba', 'ba'].some(x => x === term)
```

Comment: Just reverse the processus, don't search for pattern that is not exactly inside your list. Search for them and if you found some tell the user that it's not correct. Even better since you found something you can tell him where's wrong.

Comment: There are lots of different flavors of regex; so if you don't tell us which language you'll implement this regex in, we can't really give you an answer that's certain to work for you. Since you mentioned JavaScript offhand, I'll tag this with that; but recognize that you could have been getting downvotes because you responded flippantly about what language you'd be using this Regex in.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker that's fair, Like I said in my (deleted) comment, I didn't tag it with js because I assumed the answer was straightforward enough that differences in flavors wouldn't matter. Also, I'll note that its technically html here, not js. The `pattern` attribute uses the javascript engine, but classifying it as javascript doesn't fully sit right with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead with anchors:

```
^(?!(?:(aba|ab|ba)$)).*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jS4hJ9/3)

`(?!(?:(aba|ab|ba)$))` is negative lookahead that will fail the match if input contains exact words `ab` or `aba` or `ba`

Comment: oh, I see - your use of the `aba?` confused me. Going with `/^(?!.*\b(ab|aba|ba)\b).*$/g`

Comment: Yes I just shortened `ab|aba` to `aba?`

Comment: Looking at this now, its actually not *quite* correct. See my edit. Basically it does not match `ab a` which it should since that's not the exact string

Comment: Thanks. I managed to simplify it to `^(?!(?:(aba|ab|ba)$)).*`